# Editing XML Content in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have following XML document which i want to edit through power shell.

```
<WDA.Application.Configuration xmlns="WDA.Application.Configuration">

    <Portals>
        <Portal PortalID="abcd" Type="default" />
    </Portals>  

  <ConfigSections codeBase="c:\WDA.Applications\WDA.Net\Assemblies\Private">

  </ConfigSections>
```

I want to edit -portalid value and in ->codebase.I am returniing XPath of these two elements,but on calling Document.selectSingleNode(XPAth) on these,i am getting a null node.

The Xpath i am having is of type /WDA.Application.Configuration/Portals/Portal
Can any one please tell me how can i edit these nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
[XML]$XML = (gc C:\test.xml)
$XML.Item("WDA.Application.Configuration").Portals.Portal.PortalId = "newid"
```

Comment: thanks for reply,This worked for me.But is there a way to provide the Xpath of PortalID and the call xml.selectsingleNode(Xpath?

Comment: I assume the select node should work when provided with an xpath, but I've tried it a couple of times before, but I didn't seem to be able to get it to work so I just started using this method instead.

Comment: thank you so much,Actually for me selectSinglenoe worked,but what i analyzed is its not working because of xmlns given in the very first node.If i am replacing xmlns with any random string let say "abc",then its working perfectly Fine.